# How to learn basics of composition?

Tags: problems, composing

There are a few resources in the web for problem composers. Problem is the usually assume you are already part of the community. As a result one has to wander around to find out what is a grasshopper, a model mate, etc. I already have access to much of this information, but it would be nice to know of a single source (or few in any case) where one can learn the lingo, history, and the kind of questions that modern composers are interested in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- [CHESS PROBLEMS MADE EASY - How to solve, how to compose](http://frank.strmilov.cz/taverner.pdf)
- [How to compose chess problems and why](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2929666?uid=3738432&uid=2134&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102629982447) (You have to register for free to read it)
- [Chess Wizardry: The New ABC of Chess Problems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1879479338)
- [Compose Like Mozart](http://www.uschess.org/content/view/8745/473/)
- [What are chess problems](http://www.theproblemist.org/what-are-chess-problems)

**Additional links**

- [Chess Problems](http://www.anders.thulin.name/SUBJECTS/CHESS_PROBLEMS/)
- [The Chess Portal: Chess theory/Chess Problems](http://www.schackportalen.nu/english/eschackteori.htm) (that list has many recourses on Chess composition)

Comment: Whoa! That's plenty to keep me busy for a while. Thx!

Answer (score 8):

- http://chesscomposers.blogspot.com/p/for-beginners.html
- For definitions, see Christian Poisson's website [Problemesis](http://christian.poisson.free.fr/problemesis/numero55.html) ("Definitions" menu)
- For an encyclopaedic website, visit [Vaclav Kotesovec](http://www.kotesovec.cz/)
- The [MatPlus forum](http://matplus.net/start.php?px=1388152716&app=forum&unfold=2&act=home) is dedicated to problem chess and is frequented by chess problem enthusiasts.

(Edited December 27th: Now I can insert more than 2 links in my answer)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the great links above. Here are some more:

- [Great intro tutorials](http://www.ozproblems.com/problem-world) from a fine composer, Peter Wong.
- Incomplete but still very useful [multilingual glossary](http://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/keywords.jsp?s=all) of the keywords underpinning "Die Schwalbe" online database of 350,000+ problems.
- [Thousands of retro problems](http://www.janko.at/Retros/) with full solutions, and many articles. Minor cavil: there is a little disorganization in article structure following the announcement around 2009 of some technical changes around in castling and e.p. conventions.
- A popular [forum for fairy chess](http://juliasfairies.com/fairy-terms/) with very good technical articles by top composers.